NextJS DatoCMS the whole application dynamically static generated
I'm trying to build an application with NextJS and DatoCMS, the idea is to have a highly customizable website with a couple a components. A editor in DatoCMS can add a page, add some components with custom content and build the website that way.
I'm using the AppRouter of NextJS, and my folder structure is currently looking like this:

src

app

[slug]





Which works fine for every page like /slug but for the homepage I can't seem to do it.
In DatoCMS the idea would be for the editor to put a custom slug, currently it's set to _.
I didn't want to make a special place for the homepage in DatoCMS, I'd like it to be just a normal page like all the others.
I deleted the page.js in the root and in src/app/[slug]/page.jsx I have this
export const dynamicParams = false

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const { allPages } = await performRequest(PAGE_CONTENT_QUERY);
  return allPages.map((pages) => ({
    slug: pages.slug == "_" ? "" : pages.slug,
  }))
}

But I guess when I add the "" it tries to go to the page.js that I deleted.

It wasn't exactly what I wanted but it's the only way I found to do this.
I resorted to have 2 different pages but they just deffer to a component.
I have this in app/[slug]/page.jsx
export default async function Home({ params }) {
  const { slug } = params;
  return <DynamicPage slug={slug} />
}

export const dynamicParams = false;

const PAGE_CONTENT_QUERY = `
  query MyQuery {
    allPages {
      slug
    }
  }
`;

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  return allPages.map((pages) => ({
    slug: pages.slug == "_" ? "" : pages.slug,
  }))
}

And in app/page.jsx I just have this:
export default async function Home() {
  return <DynamicPage slug={'_'} />
}

My component DynamicPage is the one that does all the heavy lifting
export default async function DynamicPage({ slug }) {
  const page = await getPageContent(slug);

  return (
    <div>
      {page.sections.map((section, i) => (
        <Section key={i} section={section} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

And in the sections component I just check which section it is and load it.
